# Who is this 7th soldier I have?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I'm on a guerilla op right now, and I'm seeing a seventh soldier in my squad that I don't remember adding to my squad.

They have no class (no, not even Rookie), seem to have a randomized name, and the following stats:

- 9 health
- 95 aim
- 5 hack
- 50 will

Who is this, why are they in my squad, and will I keep them once I'm done with the mission?

To clarify, I remember setting up the squad clearly, but it's a somewhat old save so I could have done something previously that I don't remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the bonus called Volunteer Army (either from continent bonus or resistance order), there will be a chance of a unclassed resistance soldier join you on missions.

There's another similar bonus called Double Agent where there's a chance of a random advent unit (stun lancer or trooper) join you on a mission.

Comment: My brother suspected that :P I wish they would get at least grenades.

Comment: Possible to have both on a mission?

Comment: Confirmed: I finished the mission and checked my Resistance orders and Volunteer Army was in it.

Comment: @StephenLeppik The Double Agent advent unit has grenades (or at least one of them does).

Comment: @RoijanEskor I was wrong.  I just had a mission where I had both an advent stun lancer and a random resistance soldier for the first time, so it is in fact possible

Comment: @lI good to know.